# Подскажите почему не работает функция удаления блока из корзины?

Tags: javascript

Извиняюсь, что не отсеял лишнее. Подскажите почему не отрабатывает кнопка del_button в корзине после добавления элементов. Что не так делаю?

42-49я строки

https://jsfiddle.net/fn1botva/1/

```
 //Функция удаления элемента из корзины
function delItem() {
    this.parentElement.remove()
}
//Обработка нажания на кнопку для удаления элементы из корзины
for (var i = 0; i < del_button.length; i++) {
    del_button[i].onclick = delItem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в создании элемента.

При [клонировании](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), клонируются атрибуты, но не клонируются обработчики навешанные с помощью `addEventListener` или свойств, например `el.onclick = ...`

Поэтому в последнем цикле, можно добавить всем атрибут:

```
del_button[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'delItem.call(this)');
```

`.call(this)` в данном случае нужен, чтобы не менять саму функцию обработчик.

При этом `delItem` должна быть объявлена глобально.

Пример:

```js
//5* Реализовать модуль корзины. Создать блок товаров и блок корзины. У каждого товара есть кнопка «Купить», при нажатии на которую происходит добавление имени и цены товара в блок корзины. Корзина должна уметь считать общую сумму заказа.
let items = document.getElementsByClassName('item'),
  recycle = document.getElementById('recycle'),
  infotext = document.getElementById('infotext'),
  summ = document.getElementsByClassName('summ'),
  del_button = document.getElementsByClassName('del_button')
//Функция добавления элемента в корзину
function addItem() {
  //скрываем кнопку купить
  infotext.style.display = 'none';
  //добавляем элементы в корзину
  let item_clone = this.parentElement.cloneNode(true);
  recycle.appendChild(item_clone)

  //Считаем общую сумму покупок
  let prices = recycle.getElementsByClassName('price')
  totalprice = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < prices.length; j++) {
    totalprice = totalprice + Number(prices[j].innerHTML);
    //console.log('Элемент N', j + 1, 'Сумма:', totalprice); 
  }
  console.log('TOTAL PRICE', totalprice);
  summ[0].innerHTML = 'TOTAL PRICE ' + totalprice;
}

//Обработка нажатия на кнопку для добавления элемента в корзину
let item_button = document.getElementsByClassName('item_button');
for (var i = 0; i < item_button.length; i++) {
  item_button[i].onclick = addItem;
};
//Очистка корзины 
let buttonClear = document.getElementById('clear');
buttonClear.onclick = function() {
  //очистка начального текста корзины
  recycle.innerHTML = ''
  recycle.appendChild(infotext)
  infotext.style.display = 'block';
  //очистка блока с общей суммой покупок
  summ[0].innerText = '';
}

//Функция удаления элемента из корзины
function delItem() {
  this.parentElement.remove()
}

//Обработка нажания на кнопку для удаления элементы из корзины
for (var i = 0; i < del_button.length; i++) {
  del_button[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'delItem.call(this)');
}
```

```css
button {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 132px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

button:hover {
  color: purple;
  background-color: white;
}

p {
  color: #010101;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item p {
  color: rebeccapurple;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.Container {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: White;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  height: 2000px;
}

.summ {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #010101;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px
}

.Recycle {
  margin-left: 0 auto;
}

.Recycle h1 {
  padding-left: 200px;
}

#recycle {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#recycle .item_button {
  display: none;
}

.del_button {
  display: none;
}

#recycle .del_button {
  display: block;
}

.Items {
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5%;
  height: 454px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-image: url(big/Layer8.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#recycleButton {
  float: right;
}

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 49.542px;
  text-align: center;
}

.infoblock {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id='container' class='Container'>
  <h1>OUR TRENDING PRODUCTS</h1>
  <div class='Items'>
    <div class='item' id='01' onclick>
      <img src='small/image1.jpg'><br>
      <p class='price' id='1'>1000</p>
      <button class='item_button'>BUY IT</button>
      <button class='del_button'>Del</button>
    </div>
    <div class='item' id='02' onclick>
      <img src='small/image2.jpg'><br>
      <p class='price' id='2'>2000</p>
      <button class='item_button'>BUY IT</button>
      <button class='del_button'>Del</button>
    </div>
    <div class='item' id='03'>
      <img src='small/image3.jpg' onclick><br>
      <p class='price' id='3'>3000</p>
      <button class='item_button'>BUY IT</button>
      <button class='del_button'>Del</button>
    </div>
    <div class='item' id='04'>
      <img src='small/image4.jpg' onclick><br>
      <p class='price' id='4'>4000</p>
      <button class='item_button'>BUY IT</button>
      <button class='del_button'>Del</button>
    </div>
    <div class='item' id='05'>
      <img src='small/image5.jpeg' onclick><br>
      <p class='price' id='5'>5000</p>
      <button class='item_button'>BUY IT</button>
      <button class='del_button'>Del</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='RecycleContentFields'>
    <h1>RECYCLE</h1>
    <div class='recycleContent'>
      <address></address>
    </div>
    <div class='infoblock'>
      <p class='summ'>TOTAL SUMM</p>
      <button id='clear'>CLEAR RECYCLE</button>

    </div><br>
    <div id='recycle' onclick>
      <div id='infotext'>YOUR RECYCLE IS CLEAR</div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```